# Infinite intersection of topological subspaces. What is its topoloy?

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

If I have a decreasing sequence (infinite, at least countable) of subspaces of topological vector spaces:

$$\ldots E_{n+1} \subseteq  E_n \subseteq \ldots \subseteq E_2 \subseteq E_1$$

What is the topology of the intersection?

$$ E = \cap_{i}E_i $$

considering that the topology of $E_n$ is the subspace topology induced by $E_{n-1}$. What I'm thinking is that a possible subbase of the topology is $\{U_i\cap E: U_i \mbox{ is open on }E_i\}$. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your question contains: (a) the assumption of some topological spaces $E_n$-s; (b) some mutual properties that the topologies on the $E_n$-s must satisfy; (c) the definition of a set $E$. Since you have neither *defined* nor *described* in terms of other datas a topology on $E$, the question as it stands has no real answer.

Answer (score 0):

The subspace topology on $E_n$ induced by $E_{n-1}$ is the same as the subspace topology on $E_n$ induced by $E_1$. So the most reasonable choice for $E$ would be the subspace topology induced by $E_1$.